# Adding a scatterplot to a coefficient plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a coefficient plot with a scatterplot of data points laid overtop of it. A portion of the data are listed below:

```
print(dat)

                   lower    upper      mode    condition   obsMean p100 p102 p103 p104 p105
ob.h.Black.650  0.693595 0.950305 0.8849853  h.Black.650 0.8122302 0.85 1.00 0.85 0.85 0.85
ob.h.White.650  0.649625 0.930375 0.8306119  h.White.650 0.7852518 0.70 0.95 0.80 0.80 0.90
ob.h.Black.800  0.833255 0.993105 0.9701335  h.Black.800 0.9035971 0.95 1.00 0.95 0.95 1.00
ob.h.White.800  0.802110 0.983230 0.9469604  h.White.800 0.8762590 0.95 0.95 0.80 1.00 0.85
ob.h.Black.950  0.869375 0.995800 0.9804180  h.Black.950 0.9165468 0.90 1.00 0.85 1.00 1.00
ob.h.White.950  0.862895 0.991750 0.9694811  h.White.950 0.9046763 1.00 1.00 0.95 1.00 0.90
ob.h.Black.1100 0.879340 0.996550 0.9885382 h.Black.1100 0.9323741 1.00 1.00 0.90 0.75 0.85
ob.h.White.1100 0.853110 0.994405 0.9773240 h.White.1100 0.9140288 0.95 0.95 1.00 0.90 0.90
```

My code produces output shown below:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = reorder(condition, 1:8), y = mode)) + #X is cond, Y is mode
  geom_point(size = 4) + #Add in black dots for the modes
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) + #Add in 95% HDI bars
  geom_point(aes(x = reorder(condition, 1:8), y = obsMean), size = 4, colour = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = reorder(condition, 1:8), y = p100), #X is cond, Y is a Ps mean
    position = position_jitter(width = .2, height = 0), #jitter the data point
    size = 2, colour = "blue") +  #make it small and blue
  geom_point(aes(x = reorder(condition, 1:8), y = p102), #X is cond, Y is a Ps mean
    position = position_jitter(width = .2, height = 0), #jitter the data point
    size = 2, colour = "blue") +  #make it small and blue
  geom_point(aes(x = reorder(condition, 1:8), y = p103), #X is condition, Y is a Ps mean
    position = position_jitter(width = .2, height = 0), #jitter the data point
    size = 2, colour = "blue") +  #make it small and blue
  geom_point(aes(x = reorder(condition, 1:8), y = p104), #X is condition, Y is a Ps mean
    position = position_jitter(width = .2, height = 0), #jitter the data point
    size = 2, colour = "blue") +  #make it small and blue
  geom_point(aes(x = reorder(condition, 1:8), y = p105), #X is condition, Y is a Ps mean
    position = position_jitter(width = .2, height = 0), #jitter the data point
    size = 2, colour = "blue") +  #make it small and blue
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(.6, 1)) + #Scale the graph from .6 to 1
  ylab("Hit Rate") + #Add y axis label
  theme_bw() +  #Use black and white theme
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), #Get rid of the x-axis label
    panel.background = element_blank(), #Get rid of the background
    panel.grid = element_blank(), #Get rid of the gridlines
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1))  #Add border
```

Which produces this plot.

[image]

As you can see, the code is inefficient. For each set of points that I want to overlay on the condition mean and confidence interval, I have to enter another line of code. With 139 repetitions in the full dataset, that's particularly cumbersome. I was wondering if there was a more efficient way of overlaying the individual repetitions on the mean and CIs.

Comment: `reshape2::melt` or `tidyr::gather` your data into long form.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work. If I put the data into long form--such that the data from each participant are in a single row--then I gain the ability to plot the individual participants (e.g., "p100", "p102") scores as a function of condition, but lose the ability to plot the condition mode and mean (i.e., "mode" and "obsMean"). Perhaps you could clarify?

Comment: If you're planning on using ggplot much, I'd highly recommend reading up on [tidy data](http://vita.had.co.nz/papers/tidy-data.pdf). ggplot is built to work well with tidy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments, you should reshape your data into long form. This can be done with either `reshape2`, `data.table` or `tidyr`:

```
library(reshape2)
dat2 <- melt(dat, measure.vars = c("p100","p102","p103","p104","p105"))

library(data.table)
# method 1 (equivalent to the reshape2 method)
dat2 <- melt(setDT(dat), measure.vars = c("p100","p102","p103","p104","p105"))
# method 2
dat2 <- melt(setDT(dat), measure.vars = patterns("^p"))

library(tidyr)
dat2 <- dat %>% gather(variable, value, c(p100,p102,p103,p104,p105))
```

Next, set the factorlevels of `condition` in the correct order:

```
dat2$condition <- factor(dat2$condition, levels = c("h.Black.650","h.White.650","h.Black.800","h.White.800",
                                                    "h.Black.950","h.White.950","h.Black.1100","h.White.1100"))
```

Finally, you can simplify your plotting code as follows:

```
ggplot(dat2, aes(x = condition, y = mode)) + 
  geom_point(size = 4) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = condition, y = obsMean), size = 4, colour = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = condition, y = value), 
             position = position_jitter(width = .2, height = 0), 
             size = 2, colour = "blue") + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(.6, 1.01)) +
  ylab("Hit Rate") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1))
```

which results in the following plot:

[image]

Furthermore, you might consider coloring the blue points by the p-variables:

```
ggplot(dat2, aes(x = condition, y = mode)) + 
  geom_point(size = 4) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower, ymax = upper)) + 
  geom_point(aes(x = condition, y = obsMean), size = 4, colour = "red") +
  geom_point(aes(x = condition, y = value, color = variable), 
             position = position_jitter(width = .2, height = 0), size = 2) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(.6, 1.01)) +
  ylab("Hit Rate") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA, size = 1))
```

this results in:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This solved my problem. I'd like to add that while implementing this solution I found it more effective to specify the error bars and larger data points using a separate data frame. Otherwise the error bars are drawn repeatedly, which does not look aesthetically pleasing.